# Dictionary access inside a for loop in Swift

Tags: dictionary, swift

I'm trying to do a couple of PoC's in Swift - my first experiment is a simple card game.

I'm running into a problem trying to access a dictionary in the midst of a `for` loop:

```
let suits: Array<String> = ["Spades", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Hearts"]
let ranks: Array<Integer> = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
let rankMap: Dictionary<Int,String> = [1:"Ace", 11:"Jack", 12:"Queen", 13:"King"]

struct Card {
    let suit: String
    let rank: Integer
    let image: String? //There's some NSObject that corresponds to image resources. Later.
}

func buildDeck(NumberOfJokers:Int) -> Array<Card>{
    assert(NumberOfJokers <= 2, "Can't have more than two jokers in a deck")
    var retDeck: Array<Card> = []
    for s in suits {
        for r in ranks {
            let newSuit = rankMap[r]? //ERROR: Could not find an overload for subscript that accepts the supplied arguments
            retDeck.append(Card(suit:s, rank:r, image: nil))

        }
    }

    return retDeck
}
```

What I can't figure out is how to use the current value of `r` while looping through the `ranks` array as an identifier to pull the proper string out of the `rankMap` dictionary. Any way I can try of using the `r` integer as the dictionary key throws this "could not find an overload" message.

I understand that I'll get an Optional out of rankMap, but the unwrapping/chaining methods don't result in anything different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your array is holding `Integers` and your dictionary is using `Ints` as keys. Change the array to hold `Ints`! There is some explinations about the different types in the [basic section of the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_420).

```
// was using Integer so now use Int
let ranks: Array<Int> = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]

// is keyed with Int
let rankMap: Dictionary<Int,String> = [1:"Ace", 11:"Jack", 12:"Queen", 13:"King"]

// hence your problem.
```

Here is a simple example that shows your issue:

```
var b: Integer = 3
var c: Int = 5
let bc = b + c // throws error!
```

Comment: Hmm.. I can't force the Dictionary to use the Integer type, that throws a massive ton of errors beginning with "Type 'integer' does not conform to protocol...'.

Comment: @MikeyT.K., that is weird. For now use Int in the array. I know that dictionary keys need to be hashable, I'll see if I can dig something up.

Comment: Your last edit did it - the magic words in the docs are "`Use the Int type for all general-purpose integer constant`" - when I change the `ranks` array to use `int` instead of `integer`, all is well. Thanks!

Comment: @MikeyT.K., Yeah `Ints` are preferred. I am still intrigued that the dictionary doesn't work with Integers. Glad it worked!